# AngularJS $routeProvider otherwise catches my external redirections

Tags: angularjs, redirect, routes, external

I'm using $routeProvider in AngularJS with many routes configured. The "otherwise" section 
is configured, so it redirects all the unknown routes to the main page of my application.

All I want is to redirect the browser from my controller to an external URL, but I cant.
I tried to use $window.location = external, window.location.href = external, but they doesnt work. The routing API redirects me to the default page set in otherwise every single time.

How could I achieve this with / or without major hacks. Unfortunately, It have to be done via JavaScript code from my controller.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS's routing is for routing within the page.

You should use native location.href for this.

Edit: can you give me a plunker for this? did you try something along this line yet?

`$scope.path="http://www.google.com";
 $scope.redirect = function(path){
    location.href = path;
  };`

with

```
<button ng-click="redirect(path)">Go there</button>
```

Comment: I can't. It has no effect, redirects me as well to the main page defined in otherwise section of the $routeProvider.

Answer (score 0):

That might not fully answer your question but to navigate outside of route scope you can use this

```
Links that contain target element
    Example: <a href="/ext/link?a=b" target="_self">link</a>

Absolute links that go to a different domain
    Example: <a href="http://angularjs.org/">link</a> //this one might actually be of use for you

Links starting with '/' that lead to a different base path when base is defined
    Example: <a href="/not-my-base/link">link</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works - I know, but I have to do the redirection from JavaScript code within my controller.